# Changing OS completely on galaxy note SC-05D and galaxy s2 SC-02C

Tags: localization, operating-system

I live in Japan and I would like to get these 2 phones but both of them is sold here with Google Android 2.3.7 Japanese OS.

I was wondering if it possible to change that into a regular English version? 
If so, how to do that in detail, please explain as I am new to this.

Answer (score 1):

No need to change - language can be changed within the OS. My only tweak was installing a better English keyboard from the Play store, since the stock Samsung one isn't very good.

Comment: OS might not have all the languages.

Comment: My experience (in Korea, not Japan) is that this is correct. I've never seen an Android phone sold in Korea that didn't have English as an option in `Settings->Language & Input->Language`. I expect Japan to be the same.